# How many airbenders are there?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

How many airbenders are there in Korra's time?  If Aang was the last airbender, is it only his offspring—Tenzen and his three children—that have mastery of the element?  Many similarly garbed people were seen in the dining hall, were some Air Nomads hiding among the other nations during the war?

Comment: The answer to this was also covered already here: Why aren't there any airbenders in Profession Tournament Bending?http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14871/2765

Comment: The answer is simple. All benders who are not Firebenders, Earthbenders, Waterbenders, Energybenders, or Avatar incarnations.

Comment: @GabeWillard bit tautological.

Comment: I don't see how any other answer would answer this, though. Without verifying the identity/bending ability of every living person at the time of Korra, there's no way of knowing.

Comment: @GabeWillard It's entirely answerable.  Bending ability goes from parent to child.  How many children did Aang, **The Last Airbender**, have?  How many children did they have?  How many of all these people inherited Airbending?

Comment: @Keen It is *assumed* no Airbenders besides Aang survived. It is in the nature of Airbenders to dodge danger and avoid direct confrontation. For all we know, several of them could have escaped the Fire Nation raids and began living in a secluded area of the world, hiding their identities. This question is asking to prove a negative.

Comment: @GabeWillard Unprovable hypotheses can always be fabricated to counter proven information.  Do you have a link to anything where the show creators have indicated Aang wasn't the last Airbender?

Comment: @Keen Only the undeniable evidence of logic. And the fact that the show's creators have a penchant for showing that what is assumed to be true is not always. Dragons were extinct, as well as Sky Bison. We see in Season 3 of The Last Airbender that Dragons are not as extinct as commonly known to be, and in Legend of Korra that a previously unknown flock of Sky Bison escaped the Fire Nation attacks. Just like Aang is "The Last Airbender," Appa was "The Last Sky Bison." Negatives are simply unprovable. If the question asked "How many known airbenders are there," it would be answerable.

Answer (score 8):

The title of the previous show *Avatar: The Last Airbender* was accurate, the Fire Nation had wiped out all Airbenders while Aang was frozen.  Tenzin and his 3 children are the only Airbenders left in Korra's time.  In the S1E10, *Turning the Tides*, Lin refers to Tenzin and his kids as "the last airbenders".

If you consider the *Avatar: The Last Airbender* comics canon, then there were some airbenders who survived the initial genocide.  They were later lured with the hope of sanctuary, and killed by [Admiral Zhao](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Relics).

The others dressed in that garb are [Air Acolytes](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Air_Acolytes), who are people who seek to maintain the Air Nomad's culture while the Airbender population (hopefully) increases.  They do not have the ability to bend.

Comment: Were all the Air Nomads exterminated or just the airbenders?  (granted, IIRC virtually all Nomads were benders...)

Comment: @NickT Did we ever see non-bending Air Nomads?  We only glimpsed them via Aang's memories, and he was always surrounded by people teaching him bending and culture.

Comment: @NickT Also, I'm uncertain.  AFAIK, all Air Nomads were exterminated, as there weren't any at their Temples in Aang's time.  I guess it's possible that there are non-bending Air Nomads who hid, but we never see any in *Avatar*.

Comment: Do you have any sources for Tenzin and his kids being the only airbenders? Is it possible that Tenzin's nieces and nephews could be airbenders as well?

Comment: @Tacroy 1. All Airbenders are descendants of other Airbenders.  2. Of Aang's 3 children, Tenzin's the only Airbender.  3. I'll have to rewatch the first 2 eps of *Legend of Korra*, but I don't think there are nieces and nephews.  I thought Tenzin's kids were Katara's only grandkids.

Comment: @Tacroy Trying to find something concrete, but all I'm finding is a lack of info about Tenzin's siblings.  [This](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Transcript:San_Diego_Comic-Con_2011) has a segment on Aang and Katara's descendents, and it only briefly mentions Tenzin's siblings, then delves into Tenzin and his children.  At this point, if there are other grandchildren of Aang and Katara, they haven't been revealed.

Comment: @Keen it's step 2 I'm not sure about, since after all Mako and Bolin are brothers but bend different elements; the inheritance might be more complicated than "only if your parents bent that element". It seems unlikely to me that Aang died without seeing any grandchildren, but there's no evidence either way.

Comment: @Tacroy Aang has three children. One is a confirmed Air bender (Tenzin), one is a confirmed water-bender ( Kya)and the other is a confirmed  non-bender (Bumi) From [here](http://www.animationinsider.net/article.php?articleID=3084&document=1)

Comment: [Here's](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Transcript:Welcome_to_Republic_City) a transcript from the first ep of *Korra*, and I was wrong, it doesn't make it clear that there are no other grandchildren of Korra.  But, I did find a line that says Tenzin's the **only** Airbending master.  That means if one of his nieces or nephews was an Airbender, they'd be with him, training.

Comment: @Keen I'll accede to that, but note that Tenzin's the only Airbending **master** - given how old Kya and Bumi are, if their children are capable of airbending one of them may be a [journeyman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journeyman) who wasn't on the island for whatever reason.

Comment: I also wondered if another possible refuge of airbending (though perhaps just second-hand knowledge) was in people like [Guru Pathik.](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Guru_Pathik)

Comment: @Keen But even if they say Tenzin was the only airbending master, how could you know if they were right or just repeating common opinion?

Comment: @GabeWillard Because Korra states it several times in the episode, including to Tenzin himself.  If there was another known Airbender Master, she would have been corrected.

Comment: @Keen Emphasis on *known*. I don't think this question is answerable. You'd have to prove a negative.

Comment: @Tacroy I've added a citation.  The latest episode had a character refer to Tenzin et al. as the last airbenders.

Comment: @NickT Apparently all Air Nomads were Airbenders, per the [Avatar:TLA bible](http://racebending.livejournal.com/117598.html).

Answer (score 2):

As of Book 3, some non benders have gained air bending almost overnight, so there are much more than just Tenzin and his children.

Answer (score 1):

The show only shows you 4, Tenzen and his 3 children 2 girls and 1 boy and one boy on the way.  I didn't count the one on the way.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Book 3 Change, non-benders around the world have gained airbending. After Korra's fight with The Vaatu-Unalaq fused being, it has just been given to random people, therefore Tenzin, his children and Korra are not the only airbenders. Before this they were the only air benders. The people who dress like Air Nomads are Air Acolytes (non-benders who try to preserve the Air Nomad culture, they are not airbenders or Air Nomads). They just act and live like them and are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Book 3 introduces air bending to random people in the world that dont have bending.
The main villain in book 3 is a NON bender WHO becomes an air bender and discovers the power of flight. Previously only tought to be done by one Airbender master. ( Guru Lahima )
From the Korra wiki

> The anarchist antagonists introduced in Book Three: Change, the Red Lotus, comprise the new airbender Zaheer (Henry Rollins), the armless waterbender Ming-Hua (Grey DeLisle, who previously voiced one of the lesser dark spirits,[24]), the explosive firebender P'Li (Kristy Wu), and the lavabender Ghazan (Peter Giles). Supporting characters include the Earth Queen Hou-Ting (Jayne Taini), the retired Fire Lord Zuko (Bruce Davison), Lin's half-sister Suyin Beifong (Anne Heche), and her captain of the guards Kuvira (Zelda Williams). New airbenders are also introduced in the season including the young thief Kai (Skyler Brigmann) and Suyin's daughter Opal (Alyson Stoner), both from Earth Kingdom and love-interests of Jinora and Bolin respectively. Jim Meskimen voices a Republic City merchant and later airbender named Daw, as well as Suyin's husband and architect Baatar.